# Verify an Address with Google Maps Static API

Tags: google-maps

I use google maps static api to show maps on my website and use the following url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=usa&size=800x300&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:S|usa
```

However, if enter a non-existing address, google will return a picture like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=notexistingaddress&size=800x300&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:S|notexistingaddress
```

I would like to know, how can I determine, if an address exists or not, using google maps static api. I cannot use javascript, because this code is executed on server.

Comment: Why don't you try to compare the google return with the picture you link ? If they are same you can say the address not exist.

Comment: Because this is not a very safe way. Google may make some changes to this picture and it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index), I think that the *Google Maps Static API* has nothing (exept the way I suggest like verify the return of the picture manually or only the keyword `notexistingaddress`) to verify if an address exists or not.

The best way to do validation is I think the [**Google Geocoding API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), where you can outpout a Json / XML of a given address. The status code of `ZERO_RESULTS` which *indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results* may interest you.